# What are the rules of field-by-field constructor generation?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, aggregate-initialization

I have found that the possibility of usage of initializer list syntax for a class depends on whether or not the class fields have default values. Why?

To be precise, consider the following code:

```
class S
{
    public:
        int a;
};
...
int a;
S s{ a };
```

It compiles without any problems. But if I add a default value to the class field, it stops building:

```
class S
{
    public:
        int a = 0;
};
...
int a;
S s{ a };
```

> Error    1    error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'S'

Why? What else influences such constructor generation?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In *C++14*, your code is valid and should compile with any C++14 compatible compiler.

---

In *C++11* however:

If you do not have a default value for `a`, your type is an aggregate, and thus [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) can be performed:

> An aggregate is one of the following types:
>
> - array type
> - class type (typically, struct or union), that has
>
>   - no private or protected non-static data members
>   - no user-provided constructors , including those inherited from public bases (since C++17) (explicitly defaulted or deleted constructors are allowed) (since C++11)
>   - no virtual, private, or protected (since C++17) base classes
>   - no virtual member functions
>   - no default member initializers (**since C++11, until C++14**)

As soon as you add a default value for the attribute `a`, your aggregate initialization cannot be performed anymore since your type stop being an aggregate.

Answer (score 4):

The shown code compiles without any issues with gcc 6.1.1. You're likely using an older compiler that does not fully support C++14:

```
$ cat t.C
class S
{
public:
  int a = 0;
};


void foo()
{
    int a=4;

    S s{a};
}
$ g++ -std=c++1z -g -c -o t.o t.C
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 6.1.1 20160510 (Red Hat 6.1.1-2)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: thank you very much. I use MSVC++ 2013, and it's the problem.

Comment: The question was tagged `c++11`, though, and this doesn't explain why the version matters.

Answer (score 2):

In both cases the default constructor of `S` takes no arguments.  The form of the class does not affect the generation of the default constructor.  Further, there is no implicitly-generated constructor taking `int`.

If `S` is an *aggregate*, then the usage `S s = { arguments_opt };` does not invoke `S`'s constructor.  Instead it invokes something called *aggregate initialization*.  Aggregates are the only classes such that objects of that class can be created without a constructor invocation.

Only if `S` is **not** an aggregate, does `S s = { arguments_opt };` try to match the argument list to the parameters of a constructor of `S`.

(As explained by others, in C++11, providing a *brace-or-equal-initializer* for a non-static data member makes the class not be an aggregate).